# tableview to detailviewcontroller storyboard issue

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, objective-c-2.0

Here's my problem. I have data being passed into the 'second view controller' by mySQL which currently works great. But when I select on any of the from (`UITableView`) cells, I am currently not able to open a new view to show the data.

I believe the code issue is with

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
detailedViewController *productinfo = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"productDetails"];

//Retrieve current user array
foodProducts *currentProduct = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
productinfo.productName = currentProduct.productName;
productinfo.productImage = currentProduct.productImgUrl;
productinfo.productDescription = currentProduct.productDescription;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:productinfo animated:YES];

}
```

There have been others who have over came this using nibs but not storyboard.

Can someone point out where I have gone wrong or something I have fundamentally missed?

(I have another project which fully working with navigation controller only. Though this is the 1st project which I have tried to use with the tab bar navigation).

Comment: Can you verify that `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` gets called? If not, check that you have set your tableview's delegate property.

Comment: I can verify `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` gets called. As I used an NSLog statement to send back to the console. <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> has been declared for the detailedViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this with a storyboard is to create a segue to the detail view from your mainViewController. This can be from your actual cell or from the controller.  In your prepare for segue method, pass the object to the detail view. This uses a fetchedResultsController but the idea is the same. Get the selected cell and pass the object to the detail view.

Here is a sample of how you could pass it while using a segue from the cell itself. Create a segue from the tableViewCell in IB for "selection". Drag that segue to your detailViewController and set the identifier to ShowDetailView then add the following prepareForSegue method.

Make sure to have a property (foodProduct) on your detailViewController that will hold the reference to your selected object. That's what you will pass from your mainViewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetailView"]) 
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        foodProducts *currentProduct = [bakeryProductArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
        detailViewController.foodProduct = currentProduct;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this? (Still a noob at some of this stuff.)

Comment: Understand everything else except? TheObject *theObject = (Object *)[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: -- Shame I can't post images of my problem :(

Comment: Should have mentioned, I have not setup core data for this project yet.

Comment: http://threepointdesign.co.uk/shot.jpg - Thats the sotryboard layout. I can't drag a seque from table view to the detailed view controller.

Comment: You need to add a tableViewCell to your tableView. Drag one over and set it's identifier. This a great way to design tableViewCells for dynamic usage. If you don't wish to add a tableViewCell in IB you can call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetailView"]; from your didSelectRowAtIndex method of your tableView and drag your segue from the viewController itself rather than the cell.

Comment: Hopefully last question: Make sure to have a property (foodProduct) on your detailViewController that will hold the reference to your selected object. Thinking @property (nonatomic, strong) ???

Comment: Correct! Now you'll be rockin' ;-) Once you get the hang of using segues you'll fall in love with them. It creates a visual representation of your app's flow that's much easier to follow (IMO) (storyboard). In your viewWillAppear or other startup method in your detailViewController you can display the data from that object you passed earlier.

Comment: I declared @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foodProduct; and synthesis it but the issue navigator say no no no :/ I must come across as such a noob but my ios/xcode training has been so broad with nibs, storyboards. I end up loosing my way so easily :(

Comment: Missing piece of the jigsaw was a navigation controller :D

Answer (score 0):

```
try this .....

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Decriptionview *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Decription"];//@"Decription" is Storybord Id of UiViewController of Decriptionview
    detail.wndecDecription=[SortedDecription1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.wndectitle=[SorttedTitle1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.wndeclink=[SortedLink1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.wndecdate=[SorttedDate1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detail.imgeurl=[sorttedMainImage1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

}
```